# Open links of external site loaded in iframe in the same iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How could I force **iframe** to load pages in it (not in entire browser) when I navigate links of external sites.

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
```

For exemple, if I click link of **stackoverflow.com** loaded in iframe, then entire browser reloads. Is it possible to reload only iframe?

Comment: You tried using [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute?

Comment: Oh, but that `iframe` is external already, isn't it? Then it's not possible.

Comment: Not possible via JS, because the Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing the iframe content.

Comment: No, it will not be possible due to Same Origin Policy, like CBroe already pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, extrenal. It is supposed to be a browser in browser.